# crear un programa que al introducir valores de vel ini y t, me entregue dist y vel

Tags: python, funciones, python-3.7

Quiero crear un programa que al introducirle muchos valores de velocidad inicial y tiempo de vuelo en millones de años me entregue la velocidad al final de ese tiempo y la distancia recorrida, pero sólo me funciona si meto una única velocidad y un único tiempo...¿cómo hago para que me funcione para varios valores al mismo tiempo?
Yo empecé así(por ejemplo para tres valores).

```
n=3
v = np.random.uniform(900,1100,n)#velocidad inicial 
t= np.random.uniform(58,160,n)*1e6 #tiempo en millones de yr

def pos(x,v0,tt):
    global p_t, v_t, a
    Mc= rho_pc*(4./3.)*np.pi*x**3
    if Mc<=M:        
        a = G_pc*Mc/(x+delta)**2

        if x>0:    
            a = a
        else:
            a = -a
        v_t = v0 + a*tt
        p_t = x + v_t*tt + 0.5*a*tt**2
        return p_t,v_t,a 
    else:
        Mc = M
        a = - G_pc*Mc/(x+delta)**2

        if x>0:    
            a = a
        else:
            a = -a
        v_t = v0 + a*tt
        p_t = x + v_t*tt + 0.5*a*tt**2
        return p_t,v_t,a

for i in range(len(v)):
    x[i],v[i],a[i] = pos(x,v,dt)
```

Pero me sale error...realmente soy nuevo en esto y les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo, no hay necesidad de meter la función en el for, simplemente hay que llamar la función desde el for y listo, yo lo solucioné así.

```
for ii in range(len(v)):

    final = pos(x0_pc,v1_pc[ii],t[ii])
    F.append(final)

F = np.array(F)
```